# Ask Ubuntu Answer Section all over the page - Bug Report

Tags: bug, bug-reports, site

AskUbuntu answer sections appear to be broken, their layout/css is out of wack on multiple freshly installed browsers. Tested latest version of Google Chrome and Firefox on Linux Mint and Debian Linux. See image below for more details. If you want this post to be a real question then how was the site broken and when will it be fixed?
[image: Broken AskUbuntu Answers on Chromium]